# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: document

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, mass-assignment

I have two models Employee and Documents which are as follows:

**Employee.rb**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :document #,dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :age, :dob, :empNo, :first_name, :gender, :last_name, :middle_name, :document_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :document
  validates :first_name, presence: true , length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :empNo, presence: true, uniqueness:{ case_sensitive: false }
  validates_length_of :empNo, :minimum => 5, :maximum => 5

  #before save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
end
```

**Document.rb**

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee,foreign_key: "empno"
  attr_accessible :idate, :iedate, :insuranceno, :iqamano, :iqedate, :iqidate, :passportno, :pedate, :pidate, :vedate, :vidate, :visano
end
```

and the controller file is **employees_controller.rb**(I have only shown new,create,show funcs)

```
  def show
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    @document=Document.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @employee }
    end
  end

  # GET /employees/new
  # GET /employees/new.json
  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
    @document= Document.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json=>{:employee=> @employee,:document=>@document}, status: :created, :location=>{:employee=> @employee,:document=>@document} }
    end
  end

  # POST /employees
  # POST /employees.json
  def create
    @employee = Employee.create!(params[:employee])
    @document = Document.create!(params[:document])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.save and @document.save
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json=>{:employee=> @employee,:document=>@document}, status: :created, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When I create a new employee I get the following error

```
 ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in EmployeesController#create
 Can't mass-assign protected attributes: document
```

The requsts parameters are fine as seen below

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"vXSnbdi+wlAhR5p8xXvTWhi85+AVZgOZufClx73gc8Q=",
 "employee"=>{"empNo"=>"11111",
 "first_name"=>"Thaha",
 "middle_name"=>"Muhammed",
 "last_name"=>"Hashim",
 "age"=>"25",
 "gender"=>"M",
 "dob(1i)"=>"2014",
 "dob(2i)"=>"7",
 "dob(3i)"=>"18",
 "document"=>{"passportno"=>"bycucde63"}},
 "commit"=>"Create Employee"}
```

I have gone through nearly all posts on stackoverflow dealing with this issue and mostly the issue is related to

1. not using `attr_accessible`
2. not using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
3. not using `:document_attributes`

If I change the value of `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` to false then the error goes away(There is a warning in developer log about the same) and ***both the models are created but only attributes of employee model is filled with passed values wheras the attributes of document model is nil.***

**EDIT #1**
If I tried to add :document to attr_accessible then I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in EmployeesController#create
```

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Understanding Mass Assignment**

Mass Assignment is the name Rails gives to the act of constructing your object with a parameters hash. It is "mass assignment" in that you are assigning multiple values to attributes via a single assignment operator.

The following snippets perform mass assignment of the name and topic attribute of the Post model:

```
Post.new(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")

Post.create(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")

Post.update_attributes(:name => "John", :topic => "Something")
```

In order for this to work, your model must allow mass assignments for each attribute in the hash you're passing in.

There are two situations in which this will fail:

You have an `attr_accessible` declaration which does not include `:name`

You have an `attr_protected` which does include `:name`

It recently became the default that attributes had to be manually white-listed via a attr_accessible in order for mass assignment to succeed. Prior to this, the default was for attributes to be assignable unless they were explicitly black-listed attr_protected or any other attribute was white-listed with attr_acessible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way here would be, i suppose, to add :document to attr_accessible.
If an attribute is not listed there, ActiveRecord will not allow you to "mass-assign" them.

Relating to my comment, you'd end up with something like this:

```
...   
"dob(3i)"=>"18",
"document"=><#Document ...>}, # {"passportno"=>"bycucde63"} is just a Hash, not a Document, that's why it raises "ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch"
"commit"=>"Create Employee"}
```

In the code, like:

```
def create
  @document = Document.create!(params[:document])
  @employee = Employee.create!(params[:employee].merge(:document => @document))
```

Comment: See the Edit in question.It doesnt work. adding `:document_attributes` was supposed to be the work around accd to many posts here in SO even that doesnt work for me

Comment: Ah, I think, I got it. Try this: You would have to convert/create a Document out of the "document"-field. Since there are just values there, AR will not automatically create a Document out of "document"=>{"passportno"=>"bycucde63"}. It's just a Hash. So adding :document to attr_accessible and then first creating a Document (out of :document param) and then mass-assign to Employee

Comment: I will try this out. but check this out http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes . Why is it not working anymore?